# How to use sphinx-build programatically?

Tags: python-sphinx

I would like to know if it is possible to import sphinx in python and setup and run the build command directly in python using sphinx's internal API. I don't want to create an extension, I just want the same result as running `sphinx-build` from the command line and passing options to it.

I know I can just set variables in conf.py but I would like to know if there is another way.